# dependency:resolve and :tree resolve different dependencies?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

When I run dependency:tree on my pom.xml I get the following output:

```
...
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ com.test.client ---
[INFO] assemblies:com.test.client:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- foundation:com.test.core:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.11:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] \- assemblies:com.test.security:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
...
```

When I run dependency:resolve on the same pom I get:

```
...
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    assemblies:com.test.security:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    foundation:com.test.core:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    junit:junit:jar:4.11:compile
[INFO]    org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
...
```

Why is the version of `com.test.core` different between :resolve and :tree?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in Maven 3.0.4. I updated to version 3.2.1 and now dependency:tree and :resolve are resolving the same dependencies.